# How to determine if a freelance writing website is reputable and provides assignments that are worthwhile?

Tags: websites, freelance

I know of the sites Elance, guru and Odesk for finding freelance writing work.  I am interested in finding others.  How can I search for them?  Is there a list or resource anywhere?  When I find sites how can I determine if they are worth my time? What criteria should I be looking for when evaluating these sites?

Comment: Welcome to Writers.  Unfortunately this question as phrased is a poll.  If edited to something along the lines of "How can you determine if an online freelance writing site is reputable and provides writing assignments that are worthwhile?" it may fit our site better.

Comment: oh..ok I will edit the title but I also wanna know which other sites are there other than those three. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately that's not a question that is a good fit for this site.  Open-ended, poll-style questions do not work well for this format.  I have edited your question to one that may work better.  Hope it helps!

Comment: Did a little tweaking on the title and added a sentence to the body of the question that I think will help. @justkt - I share your concerns for questions like this, but I *think* this is now okay to leave open.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to evaluate a freelance site is the same as evaluating any other business: Talk with the people who've worked with them before and see what they think about them, search around for other references to them to see what negative comments they have, and check their local Better Business Bureau for comments.

Don't be afraid to ask writers who do freelance work for their opinions on both who they work with and who they won't work with. They might also be able to put you into contact with people who watch for and monitor scams.

As always the core rules still apply. If it looks to good to be true it probably is, and money flows towards the author. Keep both of these in mind when looking over any freelance site.

Comment: Regarding the tip of the Better Business Bureau - quite honestly they are horrible for any information. All the BBB does is charge a few hundred per year for the privilege of putting an emblem on your website. As far as dispute resolution they are useless because none of it is binding and typically in service professions it's hard to get leverage. Typically you'll find the BBB associated with contractors and blue collar companies - but not white collar workers.